# Handle large number of rows in react native

Tags: reactjs, ajax, react-native, redux, mobile

**TechStack**:

1. React Native
2. Redux

One of my screen in react native app has list of people registered in the application. It can have thousands of rows. I am planning to have a infinite scroll. What i am concerned is how to keep those rows.

Shall i use redux to keep the rows in the state or shall i store them in a simple variable that keeps on updating.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kinda features your list has.

if your list is **only for display**, simply store your list inside **useState**.

if your list items have a **very nested component structure** until
using data to display,
redux can help you to prevent **prop drilling**.

if your data **can change from many places** and you are worried about losing tracking of data
redux can help you.